# How can I have my shell always start in a certain directory that is not my home directory

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, login, command-line

I've tried putting

```
cd /Users/my_name/my_directory/structure
```

in both `.bashrc` and `.bash_login` but neither works, i.e. when I open a new terminal window I am in my home (/Users/my_name/) directory.

No error messages, just not cd'd into the directory as hoped when starting a new terminal window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Gerry mentioned, `.bashrc` is not read by login shells. New tabs are login shells by default in Terminal and iTerm 2. `.bash_login` is only read if there's no `.bash_profile`.

You could also add a `cd` command to `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 64):

First of all, if you are not using iTerm2 already, I suggest you download this free software as a replacement for Terminal.app.

Among many other extra features, in iTerm Preferences, you can configure the default working directory for new shells. You'll find these settings in Profiles - General.

[image: iTerm Default Working Directory]

The advantage here is that you can set different behaviors for opening a new window vs opening a new tab or even creating a new split pane. I personally like staying in the current working directory when adding a split pane, for example.

You could do it in your startup script as well (though I find the iTerm solution cleaner, or at least more flexible), but then I advise you to use `~/.bash_profile` instead.

`~/.bashrc` is **not** automatically sourced when opening a new shell window, and `~/.bash_login` is only sourced if no `~/.bash_profile` is present.

Comment: I always source my .bashrc from my .bash_profile so I don't have to remember which is called from where.

Comment: @CajunLuke I do something quite similar: https://github.com/gerryvdm/dotfiles

Comment: If modifying Working Directory’s “Directory” field has no effect, you probably need to switch Command from “Command” to “Login shell” ([source](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/iterm2-discuss/pkbJJ9MwJNo/KKjkqihneZ4J)).